# Save output of NetworkManager monitor command to text file

Tags: bash, networkmanager

How can I save the output of the NetworkManager command that listens for and prints the current activity?

The command is `nmcli monitor` (https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html).

Comment: You could try [stdout redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)

Comment: If you still want to see the output on the terminal use `nmcli monitor | tee file`.

Answer (score 0):

## Logging Messages

I will show how to modify the logging levels by NetworkManager.

NetworkManager supports on the fly changing of the logging levels and allows for a fine control over what is logged.

#### First check what is the current configuration by below command:

```
root@hostname ~: nmcli general logging
```

#### As a result you will be presented with the information about current conf:

```
LEVEL  DOMAINS INFO PLATFORM,RFKILL,ETHER,WIFI,BT,MB,DHCP4,DHCP6,PPP,IP4,IP6,AUTOIP4,DNS,VPN,SHARING,SUPPLICANT,AGENTS,SETTINGS,SUSPEND,CORE,DEVICE,OLPC,INFINIBAND,FIREWALL,ADSL,BOND,VLAN,BRIDGE,TEAM,CONCHECK,DCB,DISPATCH,AUDIT,SYSTEMD
```

#### It is possible to change the level either globally or for each domain separately. The command to achieve this is:

```
 nmcli general logging [level <level> [domain <domain>]]
```

#### The < level > is the desired log level, here are some examples:

***ERR***: will log only critical errors

***WARN***: will log warnin messages

***INFO***: will log various informational messages

***DEBUG***: enables verbose logging for debugging purposes

***< domain >*** is the category of messages that shall be logged with given severity.

***WIFI***: will include only WiFi related messages, IP4 will include only IPv4 related messages

And so on, i cant provide info for every setting but this is how it works in general.

## Other things you may wanna try:

#### Systemd:

```
journalctl -u NetworkManager > tomyfile.txt
```

#### Use debug mode in general:

```
sudo /usr/lib/NetworkManager/debug-helper.py --nm debug > tomyfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to log the output of `nmcli monitor` to a file using:

```
nmcli monitor >> log.txt
```